# Spring - How to inject String value to constructor?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, code-injection

I have following component:

```
@Component
public class ServiceManagerImpl implements ServiceManager {

  private final ServiceA serviceA;
  private final ServiceB serviceB;
  private final String path;

  @Autowired
  protected ServiceManagerImpl(ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB, String path) {
    this.serviceA= serviceA;
    this.serviceB= serviceB;
    this.path= path;
  }

(...)

}
```

Now I want to create simple service to which I will inject above component with specific path value. This value should come from class with String constans:

```
@Component
public class ServiceManagerClientImpl implements ServiceManagerClient {

  private ServiceManager serviceManager;

  @Autowired
  public ServiceManagerClientImpl(ServiceManager serviceManager) {
    this.serviceManager = serviceManager;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically inject simple **path** values on ServiceManagerClientImpl level (**not** from properties / yaml files)?

Comment: Does it matter if it's a class with constants or resource like application.properties?

Comment: Use Value and Qualifier annotations in Spring Boot.

Comment: You can set it as environment variables and read from it.

Comment: @SujayMohan example?

Comment: @duffymo example?

Comment: @Andronicus Yes - I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire the Environment class

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

You can read the enironment variable("path" in your case) using the below statement.

```
environment.getProperty("path");
```